Can I override blueprint prompts?
I'm new to JHipster (I'm using JHipster v8.2.1) and I'm trying to set custom prompts to my blueprint. But for now, I can only duplicate them. Here an exemple of the problem:
In the console
? What is the base name of your application? testBlueprint
? What is the base name of your Maven parent application? (myCompanyProject) 

Here what I have done:
generators/app/generator.js
// some imports
import { askModuleName } from './prompts.js';

export default class extends extendGenerator(AppGenerator) {
  constructor(args, opts, features) {
    super(args, opts, {
      ...features,
      checkBlueprint: true,
      // Dropped it once migration is done.
      jhipster7Migration: true,
    });

    if (this.options.help) return;

    if (!this.jhipsterContext) {
      throw new Error(`This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like ${chalk.yellow('jhipster --blueprints scor')}`);
    }
  }

  async beforeQueue() {
    await super.beforeQueue();
  }

  get [AppGenerator.INITIALIZING]() {
    return this.asInitializingTaskGroup({
      ...super.initializing,
      async initializingTemplateTask() {
        this.parseJHipsterArguments(command.arguments);
        this.parseJHipsterOptions(command.options);
      },
    });
  }

  get [AppGenerator.PROMPTING]() {
    return this.asPromptingTaskGroup({
      ...super.prompting,
      askModuleName,
      async promptingTemplateTask() {},
    });
  }
}

generators/app/prompts.js
export async function askModuleName() {
  const answers = await this.prompt({
    type: 'input',
    name: 'baseName',
    message: 'What is the base name of your Maven parent application?',
    default: 'myCompanyProject',
    validate: input => {
      if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$/.test(input)) {
        return 'Your base name cannot contain special characters or a blank space';
      }
      if (input === 'application') {
        return 'Your base name cannot be named "application" as this is a reserved name for Spring Boot';
      }
      return true;
    },
    store: true,
  });

  this.config.set('baseName', answers.baseName);
}

I can either have only my prompts but without keeping the default ones, or have both without succeeding in overriding the default ones.
I don't know if I make myself clear. Don't hesitate to ask for more details.
